# How to restart explorer.exe process using Sikuli (Jython)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jython, explorer, sikuli

Task: I need to restart explorer.exe process using Sikuli.

My solution was to create batch file "RestartExplorerProcess.bat":

```
@echo off
echo Your desktop is being restored, Please wait. . .
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
echo Killing process Explorer.exe. . .
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
cls
echo Explorer.exe is killed!
echo.
echo Your desktop is now loading. . .
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
echo.
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
start %windir%\explorer.exe
echo Explorer.exe was successfully started!
exit
```

and then I called it using:

```
subprocess.Popen(Path)
```

The problem is that I need to wait the end of restarting explorer.exe before further actions.
I found 3 solutions for this:

```
1. p = subprocess.Popen(Path)
   p.wait()
2. subprocess.check_call(Path)
3. os.system(Path)
```

But all of them has same effect - Sikuli doesn't show any errors and just hangs. Maybe I am wrong, but it looks like while restarting explorer.exe process I loose some reference, and event about finishing batch file can never be executed.

So my questions are:

1. How can I restart explorer.exe process using common Sikuli (Jython) method?
2. And how can I wait finishing of my batch file using any method that was described higher?

Comment: What is causing the hang?  `Popen` or `p.wait()`?   If it's `p.wait()`, then use the default `wait()` function and specify a timeout that is greater than the time it takes to start up `explorer.exe`.  Just use a unique image for when explorer.exe restarts.

Answer (score 0):

To start/restart Firefox (or Internet Explorer) with Sikuli I use the following:

```
# Path to Firefox executable: 
PathFirefox = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
# Open Firefox 
App.open(PathFirefox)
```

To check if an app is active you could write a definition to check if an application is active or not. 
For example:

```
def appActive(appName):
    call = 'TASKLIST', '/FI', 'imagename eq %s' % appName
    # Get the tasklist result
    proc = subprocess.Popen(call, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # Trimming lines with information
    output = proc.communicate()[0].strip().split('\r\n')
    # If TASKLIST returns multiple lines, it is running. 
    if len(output) > 1 and appName in output[-1]:
        print('Result: "%s" is running!' % appName)
        return True
    else:
        print('Result: "%s" is NOT running!' % appName)
        return False

# Check if Eclipse and Firefox are running: 
appActive('eclipse.exe')
appActive('firefox.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 bats: 1 to kill and a second to  restart. After, you can check if an image of desktop exist, Here is a function.

```
def restarExplorer():
    desktop_home = "your/file/location/desktop_home.png"
    killExplorer = App("your/file/location/killExplorer.exe")
    restartExplorer = App("your/file/location/restartExplorer.exe")
    killExplorer.open()
    sleep(3) # waiting 3 
    restartExplorer.open()
    while not exists(desktop_home): # check if desktop button appears
        sleep(1) # keep waiting
    continue..
```